# Google App Engine PHP setting x frame options to same origin

Tags: php, security, google-app-engine, laravel-5.1, clickjacking

I have made an App that has recently gone through a penetration test. I am required to set the X-Frame options in the application to SAMEORIGIN. This is to prevent clickjacking. I believe this is possible in the App.yaml file, but I am not sure how to implement something like this. I have scanned the docs and still can't work out how to deny, only allow.

```
handlers:
    - url: /.*
          script: public/index.php
          http_headers:
            X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution to this using a Middleware within Laravel 5.1

The middleware is called FrameGuard and is stored at the following

> Illuminate\Http\Middleware\FrameGuard

To enable this add the following line to the protected middleware array

```
'Illuminate\Http\Middleware\FrameGuard',
```

This sets the frame header option to SAMEORIGIN, which can be changed if required.

This prevents the Clickjacking vulnerability in a Laravel application

Answer (score 0):

To anyone stumbling on this, the reason why the `http_headers` doesn't work, is because it can only be applied to static file handlers, as [mentioned in the doc.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/config/appref#handlers_element):

> Optional. You can set HTTP headers for responses of your static file or directory handlers. **If you need to set HTTP headers in your script handlers, you should instead do that in your app's code.**